# Prefixing multiple lines with a previously captured token

Tags: regex, notepad++, pcre

I'm looking for a search/replace regular expression which will capture tokens and apply them as a prefix to every subsequent line within a document.

So this..

```
Tokens always start with ##..
Nothing is prefixed until a token is encountered..
##CAT
furball
scratch
##DOG
egg
##MOUSE
wheel
on the stair
```

Becomes..

```
Tokens always start with ##..
Nothing is prefixed until a token is captured!
##CAT
CAT furball
CAT scratch
##DOG
DOG egg
#MOUSE
MOUSE wheel
MOUSE on the stair
```

Comment: If one of the answers is satisfactory, please accept it.

Comment: None are as yet, but I appreciate the effort put into answers given so far. What I would like is a solution to the problem or some reasoned argument why it is impossible (not just a naked statement "you can't do that"). I am studying to increase my knowledge of regex in the hope of providing that sort of answer myself.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this pattern:

```
search: ((?:\A|\n)##([^\r\n]+)(?>\r?\n\2[^\r\n]+)*+\r?\n(?!##))
replace: $1$2        <= with a space at the end
```

But you must apply the search replace several times until there no more matches.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is impossible. The closest I can get is replacing

```
^##(.*)\r?\n(.*)
```

with

```
##\1\n\1 \2
```

Output:

```
Tokens always start with ##..
Nothing is prefixed until a token is encountered..
##CAT
CAT furball
scratch
##DOG
DOG egg
##MOUSE
MOUSE wheel
on the stair
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the pcre tag and the Notepad++ tag.
I don't think you can actually do this without a callback mechanism.
That being said, you can do it without a callback, but you need to divide
up the functionality.

This is a php example that might give you some ideas.
Note - not sure of php string concatenation syntax (used a '.' but it could be a '+').
The usage is *multi-line* mode `//m` modifier.

```
 ^                     # Begin of line
 (?-s)                 # Modifier, No Dot-All
 (?:
      (                     # (1 start)
           \#\#                  # Token indicator
           ( \w+ )               # (2), Token
           .*                    # The rest of line
      )                     # (1 end)
   |                      # or,
      ( .* )                # (3), Just a non-token line
 )
 $                     # End of line 

 # $token = "";
 # $str = preg_replace_callback('/^(?-s)(?:(\#\#(\w+).*)|(.*))$/m',
 #                    function( $matches ){
 #                         if ( $matches[1] != "" ) {
 #                              $token = $matches[2];
 #                              return $matches[1];
 #                         }
 #                         else
 #                         if ( $token != "" ) {
 #                             return $token . " " . $matches[3];
 #                         }
 #                         return $matches[3];
 #                    },
 #                    $text);
 #
```

Comment: Notepad++ is not PCRE. IIRC, it uses Boost.

Comment: NP++ isn't PCRE since version 6.0 (released 2 years ago)?